# Reference all instances of ExtJS component on a page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have created several reusable ExtJS components, similar to the following:

```
MyCustomGridPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.GridPanel, {
    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            // some other default options
        }, config);

        MyCustomFormPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }
});
```

I am then able to include this custom grid panel in pages where I need it. In some cases I will have this same grid panel on a page multiple times.

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have form panels that I would like to automatically update any grid panel that contains data related to the form panel refreshed automatically.

In the case of a single grid panel on the page, upon the successful submission of a form panel I am able to call `Ext.getCmp('the_id_of_the_grid_panel').getStore().reload()`. But with multiple instances of these grid panels, I'd like do something similar but without using an ID since an ID has to be unique. I'd like to get an array of all grid panels on the page with an identifier of some sort and call `<item>.getStore().reload()`.

My Google search and Stack Overflow search abilities have failed me and I can't seem to find anything to get me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to do something similar on our project. We need grids to communicate with each other. When data is updated in one it may require another grid to update itself. We do this by using the mediator pattern within our extjs application. We register our grid that's being edited as a sender of a certain event in this case the edit event. Then when a new row is added the mediator send a message and any other grids that are listening for that event (the edit event) receive the message/event and refresh themselves.

You can create a mediator anyway you wish. here's a starting point:

http://www.fancybread.com/blog/post.cfm/mediator-pattern-applied-to-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps extend the panel to have an array of grids. After form submission is successful, "each" over the array of stores and reload. You can decide if you want to store the grid id (and do a lookup) or a ref to the store itself.

You would, of course, have to know which grid's are tied to the form panel before hand. In other words, you have to have some way to track which grids belong to which panel initially.  Perhaps you can populate this array of grids in the afterrender of the grid.

Ultimately, you need to devise a way to store a reference to all these cmp's. I don't think there is anything in the lib that does this for you. At the most basic level.. an array of some sort that is populated with a reference in the afterrender of each cmp would, at the very least, give you something to loop over.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways to do this:

1) Maintain your own collection of these objects in some kind of global array and then push the instance on during initComponent:

```
MyApp.myGrids.push(this);
```

2) Iterate over ~all~ components then extract out the ones you want:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.all.each(function(c){
    // xtype or some other check, instanceof
    if (c.isXType('mytype')) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking I may have to go the route of keeping a global array. I'm hoping to abstract the updating of these grids so that when someone else on my team needs to use these components, all they have to worry about is including the form and it will automatically handle the updating of the grids by finding any grid on the page on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out for ExtJS v3:

```
var gridPanels = [];
gridPanels.push(new MyCustomGridPanel(opts));    

...

Ext.each(gridPanels, function (gp) {
    gp.getStore().reload();
});
```

If you plan to have an assigned name to each Grid Panel, you can use the ref property or assign it to a named object and iterate through it.

```
MyMainPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    gpNames: ['FirstName', 'Gender'],
    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            items: [{
                //make sure you create an xtype for your class
                xtype: 'MyCustomGridPanel',
                ref: 'gp'+gpNames[0]
            }, {
                xtype: 'MyCustomGridPanel',
                ref: 'gp'+gpNames[1]
            }]
        }, config);

        MyMainPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);

        Ext.each(gpNames, function (gpName) {
            this['gp' + gpName].getStore().reload();
        }, this);
    }
});
```

This is a pretty crude way of doing it, but I hope it helps illustrate the idea across.